# pandas cannot find csv file to load

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some tutorial on Edx. The file I am working with is csv. I have pandas imported and I have the working directory set to where the file is store but it always says:

> Files does not exist

or

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 108, saw 3

what do I have to do in order to not put the full file path for importing in pycharm?

Comment: Read statement and several lines of your `csv` plus line 108, please!

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

That is an error that can occur if your file is not comma delimited or if you have some field in your data that also contains commas. For example if you have numerical data in your file that contains commas as thousands separators.

This will fail with `pd.read_csv(filename)`:

```
108
1
2
108,109,104
```

Likewise this will also fail `pd.read_csv(filename)`:

```
108, [23]
2, [15]
3, [15, 17]
```

If your data is not comma separated you need to specify the separator with the `sep=` kwarg. For example:

some_file.csv

```
108|[23]
2|[15,17]
```

Trying to load this with `pd.read_csv('some_file.csv')` will fail on line 2 as it expects only one column based on the first line, and finds two values on line 2. The correct way to read this file is `pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', sep='|')`.